не могу дать время через которое выполняется функция
у меня проблема в том что я не могу дать время через которое выполняется функция. Начнём с начала: я хотел что бы при смерти игрока, высвечивался "game over" через не большой промежуток времени, но по каким то не ведомым причинам ни "Coroutine" ни "Invoke" не хотят работать в "void OnTriggerEnter2D", а в игре просто не появляется "game over". Я неделю пытался всеми возможными методами заставить работать эту задержку перед выполнением, но угробил время в пустую.
код:
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("damage"))
    {

        StartCoroutine(wait());


        IEnumerator wait()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            
            game_over.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        Destroy(gameObject);
        
    }
}

кто найдёт решение моей проблемы буду очень благодарен)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!
Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:=> Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой -как задать хороший вопрос > https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Thread.Sleep() можете попробовать

@Faraday это Unity, там такое категорически нельзя.

@aepot, хорошо, возьму на заметку )

Вы уничтожаете объект раньше времени, очевидно же
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("damage"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(wait());

        IEnumerator wait()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            
            game_over.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

На уничтоженном объекте скрипты не выполняются, корутины в том числе.

о боже, неделю страдал а решение на столько простое, спасибо огромное! хорошо что я из за своей не внимательности не подчистил "Destroy(gameObject)", так бы не знаю как мне бы объясняли проблему)
